# Mobile Google Search Result Icon/Favicon Not Showing Up

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, html, google-index

I have put link rel=icon in the HTML with 48px icon size, tried with .ico and .png but the custom main site icon is not showing up in Google Search Result (Mobile). I have request reindex in Search Console, but no luck. I know I did request reindex so many times everytime I tried changing the link rel alternatives. Btw, I can see the icon on the browser tab and Google mobile shortcut thumbnail very well.

Meanwhile, I installed Wordpress in domain subfolder and set the icon, for just couple days the icons showed up. So I copied link rel=icon from WP to my custom main site, but no luck. It’s still showing default world icon.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How long has it been since you added the icon?

Comment: About months ago.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! I assume you have seen https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9290858 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#File_format_support. If it shows in your browser tab, it should be fine. You can also have Google reindex your home page. Make sure the favicon is properly placed on the same domain and not blocked. Google can be quite slow. I have no idea how slow in showing the favicon in SERPs unfortunately. Mine just showed up without my knowing it. Cheers!!